# How do I translate a complex MySQL query that involves MySQL variables into a PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

My main goal is to get certain columns (student: last, first, middle names; section name; and current grade level) from multiple tables by joining them, mostly getting data on the 'students' table and getting other necessary data through foreign keys on the other tables ('g7/8/9/10_performance', and 'sections'). They will then be stored in an array and such.

MySQL Query:

```
SET @grade_table = (SELECT CONCAT('g', student_currentGrade, '_performance') FROM students);
SET @stmt = CONCAT('SELECT students.student_last, students.student_first, students.student_middle, students.student_currentGrade, sections.section_name 
FROM ((students LEFT JOIN (', @grade_table ,' INNER JOIN sections ON ', @grade_table,'.section_id = sections.section_id) ON ',@grade_table,'.student_id = students.student_id))');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @stmt; 
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

I used CONCAT() function to utilize the variable @grade_table as a student database will most likely contain students of differing grade levels.

Attempted PDO query inside a class function:

```
protected function getRecords() {
    $sql =
        "SET @grade_table = (SELECT CONCAT(\'g\', student_currentGrade, \'_performance\') FROM students);"
    ;
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $sql =
       "SET @stmt = CONCAT(\'SELECT students.student_last, students.student_first, students.student_middle, students.student_currentGrade, 
        sections.section_name FROM ((students LEFT JOIN (\', @grade_table ,\' INNER JOIN sections ON \', @grade_table,\'.section_id = sections.section_id)
        ON \',@grade_table,\'.student_id = students.student_id))\');"
    ;
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $sql = "PREPARE stmt1 FROM @stmt;";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $sql = "EXECUTE stmt1;";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
        $stmt = null;
        header('location: ../performances.php?error=not_found');
        exit();
    }
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I tried using the "create PHP" option in the XAMPP phpmyadmin interface to maybe help things hence the slashes on the $sql declarations. But, the function returns nothing (in this case it changes the header to "../performances.php?error=not_found").

Controller Class function that calls the above function:

```
public function loadRecords(): array
{
    $records = $this->getRecords();
    $data = [];
    while($row = $records){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I do understand that I made the code like how Frankenstein made his monster, so I'll understand if I need better organization of data in the database.

Comment: What on earth possesed you to create a table called `g7/8/9/10_performance`? Can I ask what is in there that required such an odd name

Comment: Or is that supposed to indicate you have 4 tables called `g7_performance` and `g8_performance` etc etc

Comment: Can you clearly explain what you want as an end result and in what context you'll use the result?  Your query makes more or less no sense from a practical standpoint.  There's basically no reason you should ever use concat like it is above. (Not even mentioning implied architecture)

Comment: g7/8/9/10_performance is where you went terribly wrong. why on the EARTH it is not a **single** table `student_performance` with a `grade` column to filter out grades?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes they are 4 separate tables

Comment: @MasonStedman the expected end result is an array that will be used in constructing an html table with the help of DataTables.js.

Comment: Why use MySQL variables? You can also create a PHP variable, and fetch the result from `SELECT student_currentGrade FROM students`  (when that only returns 1 variable...)

Comment: @YourCommonSense its because each grade level has different subjects, and that each of those tables contain not only the grades of each subject but also other things like attendance.

Comment: THEN this structure is wrong as well. For the goodness sake, read something on the relational databases and how the information is stored in them. the student_grades should only have student_id, **subject_id** and grade. this way it can hold any subjects from any grades

Comment: This is not how a proper database schema should look like. If you have numbers in table or column names, you most likely have made a huge design mistake somewhere. They are either completely different tables or they should be a single table with relations to other tables. What you are doing now doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Per what @YourCommonSense said you would want to have a table `classes`, and a table of dependencies for linking the `class` to a `student`.  Then your `performance` table would be `student`.`id` 1 has grade A in `class` 5 Table to map the values together.

Comment: alright, thanks for the comments! I'll try restructuring my database.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your sql to (but I also agree on most of the comments on your question ):

```
SELECT 
    students.student_last, 
    students.student_first, 
    students.student_middle, 
    students.student_currentGrade, 
    sections.section_name
FROM students
LEFT JOIN g7_performance g7 ON g7.student_id = students.student_id
                           AND students.student_currentGrade=7
LEFT JOIN g8_performance g8 ON g8.student_id = students.student_id
                           AND students.student_currentGrade=8
LEFT JOIN g9_performance g9 ON g9.student_id = students.student_id
                           AND students.student_currentGrade=9
LEFT JOIN g10_performance g10 ON g10.student_id = students.student_id
                           AND students.student_currentGrade=10
INNER JOIN sections ON sections.section_id = COALESCE(g10.section_id, g9.section_id, g8.section_id, g7.section_id) ;
```

This assumes that a student is only in one of the 'g7/8/9/10_performance' tables.

Comment: I mean they would by definition be in all of them as the grade increments.

Comment: ok, then you want, as a result, the highest grade?  That only means re-ordering the parameters to the COALESCE() function   (see edit in 1 minute)   Because COALESCE will return the first parameter which is not NULL.

Comment: I don't want anything it's not my question, just pointing out that your statement is implicitly answered.  They'll always be in all the grades they've completed, meaning the above will return the oldest one.  Seems more efficient to just make the left joins inner joins and not build a sub table via the LEFT COALESCE if that's what you wanted anyway.  Saves a step, and a lot of overhead if this was a dataset of any size.

Comment: Well, with my current setup, students' past data would be saved in the previous performance table. So, based on the comments on the main post, its a matter of restructuring my database. Thank u for the answer tho.